# Prove that a normal linear map whose only eigenvectors are 0, 1 is an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

The question is as stated above. I proved the complex case with the spectral theorem but I'm not sure how to deal with the real case. It suffices to show $T^{2} = T$ but I am not sure how to do this. The main difficulty is the fact that I do not know whether or not T's characteristic polynomial splits in the real case.

Comment: I think you need to assume that all roots of the characteristic polynomial (even the possible complex roots) are 0 or 1. Otherwise consider a rotation in the plane.

Comment: you are right. the question did not state enough information